# Test function                                  .

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

For a smooth test function \eta and some constant C is it possible to have an estimate like the following?

|grad \eta|^2 < C {\eta}^2 ?

Thanks.

Comment: @Michael Does this mean $|{\rm grad}\; \eta(x)|^2 < C \eta^2(x)\;$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^n$?

Comment: @Michael It is not valid if $\eta(x)=0$ and ${\rm grad}\eta(x)\ne0$ for some $x$.

Comment: @Andrew. You are right. The condition on \eta , which I didn't include, is that it is supported in some ball B_2, identically 1 in the ball B_1 and |grad \eta| < constant. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take any line through the support of $\eta$. Along such a line, you would have
$|d\eta/ds|\le C|\eta|$. But since $\eta=0$ on a part of the line, you get $\eta=0$ everywhere by Gronwall's inequality.

Comment: Thanks. Does the Gronwall's inequality hold in any ball or only in a real line( as Wikipedia) has it? Thanks again.